# Download RPM on windows pc then install on centos server

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Actually, i don't want to ask this as much as possible. But i'm really stuck in installing services in centOS server for 2 days. I almost browse all the pages in Google result. I'm a windows user guy and very new in Linux environment so it makes me difficult to understand all the results gave by google.

The server doesn't have option to connect to the internet. Based on my research, my only way is to download all the RPM files in a machine with internet then transfer it to my server.

Problem: I cannot find the official package list of YUM so i can download it one by one like the https://bower.io/search/. Theres a lot of downloadable files showing if i type in google "YUM php7 rpm".

Edit: Well, i am currently using YUM because i don`t know any other way to install packages in centOS. I only want to install the following :

- php7
- nodejs
- composer
- supervisor
- nginx

I don't have any access to any media :(. I just remotely access it via putty and filezilla. But i have root access.

Comment: Downloading the rpm files and then installing them is certainly possible. Use your web browser to download and if I remember correctly `rpm -i -p file.rpm`. the difficulty that you will find is that to install say php7 will require you to first install say zlib. Then you will find to install zlib you have to install something else first... This is why yum and don't were developed to work out what you actually need.

Comment: @icarus thats what i've been struggling too. I need to find their dependency first and centos doesn't have web ui for the list of packages so i can search it easily. currently i installing cygwin. i hope it helps me.

Comment: Autocorrect is annoying! Yum and dnf are the programs that do dependency resolution.

Comment: It might be worthwhile buying a very low cost vps, doing the install there, getting a package list, and then using that to guide what you need to download. Or someone reading this might be willing to give you such a list.