# How to configure epel repository manually

Tags: linux, centos, repository, redhat-satellite

How to configure epel repository manually when we do not have internet connection or subscription to the channel.

Comment: EPEL is a free repo, there isn't any subscription.

Answer (score 2):

This guide shows what needs to be done to set up EPEL on CentOS 6 & 7:

*6*

```
$ sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

*7*

```
$ yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

If you take a look at one of the RPMs you can see what files it'll set up when installed:

```
$ rpm -qlp epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-epel.preset
/usr/share/doc/epel-release-7
/usr/share/doc/epel-release-7/GPL
```

The key pieces are the `epel.repo` and the GPG key file `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7`. You can manually install these 2 files and your system will be enabled for the EPEL repo.

#### References

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: I can't connect to the outside world (I cant http and pull the repo)

Comment: You'll have to do this on another server then and use `yumdownloader` to collect your RPMS you want and then `scp` them over to the server.

Comment: None of my servers have internet connectivity. If I've epel setup on one server I would be able to create nfs mount and configure the local repo (on remote server ) using that nfs mount.

Comment: @Kiron - that would be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I've intent access to windows machine, I would be able to move/copy rpms from windows machine to linux server. But I wanted to know, is there any way that I can download all the rpms on windows machine on one go. And then move them to linux and configure a local repo?

Comment: Make a Linux VM in Virtualbox on the windows box, do it in there.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. I am restricted to install such softwares on my workstation. However I would be able to download individual rpm on my windows workstation and then moving them to linux. So far I am following this method to install ansible, gcc, gcc+ like that. However I am looking for some permanent solution.

Comment: Someone had the same Q, no A'er - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391910/download-rpm-on-windows-pc-then-install-on-centos-server.

Comment: thanks for your help. But that Q doesn't solve my query.

Comment: @Kiron yeah there really isn't a good answer to this Q, using a Linux VM or alt box is the standard way.